# Why Won't These Scripts Load Properly in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, load

Why aren't these scripts activating in Chrome, but seem to be performing fine in Firefox and Safari?

The scripts are currently placed at the end of the `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
/* -- Wrap Functions -- */
$(function() {$(".content1").wrap("<div class='wrap-content1'></div>");});
$(function() {$(".content2").wrap("<div class='wrap-content2'></div>");});

/* -- Load Functions -- */
$('#embed1').load('https://URL1 #section1-1');
$('#embed2').load('https://URL2 #section1-2');
</script>
```

Any advice or solutions?

Comment: With those quote situations, it honestly shouldn't work on any browser.

Comment: @JayHarris Ok, so how should I be formatting them then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<script>
/* -- Wrap Functions -- */
$(function() {$(".content1").wrap("<div class='wrap-content1'></div>");});
$(function() {$(".content2").wrap("<div class='wrap-content2'></div>");});

/* -- Load Functions -- */
$('#embed1').load('https://URL1 #section1-1');
$('#embed2').load('https://URL2 #section1-2');
</script>
```

Comment: Just updated the question with your quotation catch, but still no luck getting it to work in Chrome...

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your console in your chrome browser so we could see the error

Comment: screenshot? just copy the error message (if there is one)

Comment: you might miss something when selecting console's detailed error, its up to you what you want to use, there's nothing to argue about that,

Comment: There isn't any error message. Essentially, the wrap functions aren't being recognized by the load functions, thus not including them in their output. As mentioned, everything seems to be working fine in Firefox, but not as stable in Safari, and completely ignored in Chrome.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mLsck849/ can you open this in your chrome browser,

Comment: @apelidoko Yes, I am able to open your Fiddle. I have posted a question which continues the quest for a solution to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535973/some-scripts-occasionally-non-responsive-a-chrome-safari-issue. From what I've realized, there seems to be a complication/distruption of these scripts loading in Safari as well as Chrome. yet Firefox still seems to be executing them properly...